# Filter dataframe on multiple conditions within different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, data-processing

I have a sample of the dataframe as given below.

```
data = {'ID':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B','B'],
    'Date':['2021-2-13', '2021-2-14', '2021-2-14', '2021-2-14', '2021-2-15', '2021-2-14', '2021-2-14', '2021-2-15', '2021-2-15'],
    'Modified_Date':['3/19/2021  6:34:20 PM','3/20/2021  4:57:39 PM', '3/21/2021  4:57:40 PM', '3/22/2021  4:57:57 PM', '3/23/2021  4:57:41 PM',
                    '3/25/2021  11:44:15 PM','3/26/2021  2:16:09 PM', '3/20/2021  2:16:04 PM', '3/21/2021  4:57:40 PM'],
    'Steps': [1000, 1200, 1500, 2000, 1400, 4000, 5000,1000, 3500]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1
```

[image]

This data have to be filtered in such a way that first for 'ID', and then for each 'Date', the latest entry of 'Modified_Date' row has to be selected.
EX: For ID=A, For Date='2021-04-14', The latest/last modified date = '3/22/2021 4:57:57 PM', This row has to be selected.

I have attached the snippet of the how the final dataframe has to look like.

[image]

I have been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest/most straighforward is to sort by date and take the last per group:

```
(df1.sort_values(by='Modified_Date')
    .groupby(['ID', 'Date'], as_index=False).last()
)
```

output:

```
  ID       Date          Modified_Date  Steps
0  A  2021-2-13  3/19/2021  6:34:20 PM   1000
1  A  2021-2-14  3/22/2021  4:57:57 PM   2000
2  A  2021-2-15  3/23/2021  4:57:41 PM   1400
3  B  2021-2-14  3/26/2021  2:16:09 PM   5000
4  B  2021-2-15  3/21/2021  4:57:40 PM   3500
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```py
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df1["Modified_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Modified_Date"])

df_out = df1.groupby(["ID", "Date"], as_index=False).apply(
    lambda x: x.loc[x["Modified_Date"].idxmax()]
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
  ID       Date       Modified_Date  Steps
0  A 2021-02-13 2021-03-19 18:34:20   1000
1  A 2021-02-14 2021-03-22 16:57:57   2000
2  A 2021-02-15 2021-03-23 16:57:41   1400
3  B 2021-02-14 2021-03-26 14:16:09   5000
4  B 2021-02-15 2021-03-21 16:57:40   3500
```

---

Or: `.sort_values` + `.groupby`:

```py
df_out = (
    df1.sort_values(["ID", "Date", "Modified_Date"])
    .groupby(["ID", "Date"], as_index=False)
    .last()
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also sort_values and drop_duplicates:

First convert the 2 series to dates (since they are strings in the example):

```
df1["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Date"])
df1["Modified_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Modified_Date"])
```

---

Then sort values on Modified_date and drop_duplicates keeping the last values:

```
out = df1.sort_values('Modified_Date').drop_duplicates(['ID','Date'],keep='last')\
         .sort_index()
print(out)

  ID       Date       Modified_Date  Steps
0  A 2021-02-13 2021-03-19 18:34:20   1000
3  A 2021-02-14 2021-03-22 16:57:57   2000
4  A 2021-02-15 2021-03-23 16:57:41   1400
6  B 2021-02-14 2021-03-26 14:16:09   5000
8  B 2021-02-15 2021-03-21 16:57:40   3500
```

Comment: I never checked, but I'm wondering if drop_duplicates actually uses groupby behind the scene

Comment: @mozway Good question , I havent checked either , however, `drop_duplicates` works faster than `groupby` , I am guessing it could store a `md5` like hashkey and then creates a distinct based on the index

Comment: I had a very quick look, but unfortunately it is not easy to read (lots of checks and dependencies), but I think you're probably right.